# What does the 8 stand for in the Cantor pairing function?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, number-theory, functions, algorithms

1. What does the "8" stand for in the [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function) (which assigns a natural number to each pair of natural numbers)?
2. Can I change it, or is it constant?
3. The other function for getting the unique number when you use the two inputs, doesn't use "8" in its calculations, so why did the 8 gives us the right answer?

Below is the formula to find x and y such that π(x, y) = 1432:

8 × 1432 = 11456,

11456 + 1 = 11457,

√11457 = 107.037,

107.037 − 1 = 106.037,

106.037 ÷ 2 = 53.019,

⌊53.019⌋ = 53,

so w = 53;

53 + 1 = 54,

53 × 54 = 2862,

2862 ÷ 2 = 1431,

so t = 1431;

1432 − 1431 = 1,

so y = 1;

53 − 1 = 52,

so x = 52; thus π(52, 1) = 1432.

To calculate π(52, 1):

52 + 1 = 79,

53 + 1 = 54,

53 × 54 = 2862,

2862 ÷ 2 = 1431,

1431 + 1 = 1432,

so π(52, 1) = 1432.

Comment: As described on the Wikipedia ["pairing function" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Inverting_the_Cantor_pairing_function), the algorithm for retrieving $x$ and $y$ involves solving $w^2+1w-2t=0$. By the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula), the solution involves the square root of the expression $$1^2-4\cdot 1\cdot(-2t) \qquad\text{that is,}\qquad 8t+1$$ So, the $8$ is definitely a constant. Whether there's some deep "meaning" to the value ... I don't know.